# Draw or write on a clustergram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to draw grid lines on top of a [clustergram](http://de.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/clustergram.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) in MATLAB, but don't know how to do it.
The problem is, it does not even write text:

```
cgo = clustergram(rand(30,50), 'Standardize', 'Column');
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on')
gca
hold on
text(3,4,'abcde')
```

**Edit**: I am actually not trying to write text, but draw grid lines on the heatmap of clustergram. Since (as far as I know) there is not a direct function for doing that, I was planning to plot horizontal and vertical lines manually.

Comment: Did you try using `annotation` with a textbox (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#inputarg_shapeType)?

Comment: Thank you, that works. But actually my aim is not to write a text, it was just an example. My aim is to plot grid lines on the clustergram, meaning drawing lines on it. I can do that by running `annotation('line', [.2 .2], [0 1])` multiple times with according coordinates, but since the coordinates for `annotation` should be between 0 and 1, it is hard to estimate where the grid lines should be in terms of those 0-1 coordinates. Is there a more straightforward way to plot lines on a clustergram where you can give axis values as the coordinates? Or is there an automatic way to plot grid lines?

Comment: I don't have access to `clustergram` so I can't test it but try `set(cgo, 'EdgeColor', 'k');` To get this to work you might have to play around inside the `cgo` object to find the actual heatmap object without the dendrograms. Use the object explorer for that.

Comment: The clustergram object does not have any children with an EdgeColor property. What it has is 'MATLAB_Rotate3D_Axes', 'GroupDotContextmenu', 'HeatMapTitleAxes', 'HeatMapAxes', 'DendroColAxes', 'DendroRowAxes', 'figMenuHelp', 'figMenuWindow', 'figMenuDesktop', 'figMenuTools', 'figMenuFile', 'FigureToolBar' and those are of classes 'uicontrol', 'axes', 'uicontextmenu' or 'uimenu'. None of them looks like to correspond to the heatmap object. clustergram does not have the heatmap object in its members either.

Comment: `HeatMapAxes` sounds promising... maybe try looking at its [undocumented axis rulers](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-rulers) if you can get access to them

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uistack` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html to change the z ordering of the elements in your plot.

```
cgo = clustergram(rand(30,50), 'Standardize', 'Column');
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on')
gca
hold on
t=text(3,4,'abcde','color','w')
uistack(t)
```

---

I edited the code to change the color of the text to white to make it easier to see

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how this can solve the problem because I don't think that the reason why we don't see the text is the order of the text object in the z-axis. And when I try that code, I can still cannot see the text. Does that work for you?

Comment: @user5054 Are you still trying to write text? Or are you trying to get grid lines? If the latter then I suggest you change the title and wording of the question.

Comment: @user5054 yes, I can see the text, maybe because its random data and the text is small it match a black region, try a longer string and you should be able to see it

Comment: @user5054 I changed the code so the text is white, so it's easier to see

Comment: Interesting. I cannot see any text anywhere with the updated code either.

Comment: That is strange indeed, I'm working on Matlab 2015b on MacOS 10.8, maybe it's platform dependant. Mayb you can try to plot in 3D and view from the top

Answer (score 0):

For me the above suggested solution did not work either (on R2016a, PC), but the following does:

```
cgo = clustergram(rand(30,50), 'Standardize', 'Column');
foo = plot(cgo);
ht=text(3,4,'abcde','color','y','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold','parent',foo)
uistack(ht,'top')
hl = line([0,50],[0,30],'color','y','linewidth',3,'parent',foo)
uistack(hl,'top')
```